# How would I provide access to my Windows V:\ drive in a docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, mapped-drive

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.1"

networks:
  lan_access:
    driver: bridge

services:
  nodejs:
    image: node:18
    environment: 
      - VS_ALLOW_ADMIN=true
      - VS_ALLOW_CORS=true
      - VS_PORT=8000
      - VS_VIDEO_SOURCE=/video
      - VS_ZIDOO_CONNECT=http://192.168.42.71:9529/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    working_dir: /home/app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nodejs:/home/app
      - "some way to point at my V:\ drive needs to go here":/video
    command: ["node", "app.js"]
```

Everything else seems to be working now, but either I end up with a `docker-compose.yml` syntax error, or my `/video` drive is empty when the server launches. I need `/video` to provide access to everything on my mapped network `V:\` drive.

**UPDATE:** Since I have Docker on Windows running using WSL, I tried mounting my `V:\` in WSL as `/mnt/v`. WSL sees all of the files on the drive that way, but using `/mnt/v` as my volume source didn't help, unfortunately.

**UPDATE 2:** I can mount all of my C drive like this:

```yaml
    volumes:
      - ./nodejs:/home/app
      - type: bind
        source: c:/
        target: /media/video
```

That works perfectly. If I substitute `v:/` for `c:/`, however, all I see is an empty directory. There is no error message, no warning, but nothing appears.

If I use an unmapped drive letter, like `q:/`, I do get an error:

> Error response from daemon: mkdir q:: The system cannot find the path specified.

First of all, it's weird that the error comes from `mkdir`. Secondly, this tell me Docker can indeed find my V drive, but it then either fails silently in some other manner, or Docker deliberately filters the content of the V drive.

A permissions issue? Docker Desktop *used to* have a Shared Drives section in its Settings, but that doesn't exist any more, so if there is a way that I need to provide permission to access the contents of the V drive, I don't know what that is.