# Why isn't this attempt to mount a SMB share in my Docker compose file working (invalid argument)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, smb

I've got this entry in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
volumes:
  video:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: "username=guest,password=guest"
      device: "//192.168.42.13/video"
```

This looks like examples I've found (although some examples add user ID arguments and other things to the "o" parameter), but I keep getting this error:

```
c:\git\docker-nodejs>docker-compose up

[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                 docker:default
Attaching to docker-nodejs-nodejs-1
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker-nodejs_video/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount 192.168.42.13/video:/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker-nodejs_video/_data, data: username=guest,password=********: invalid argument
```

I've tried a few variations on this (like adding "smb:" to the IP address), but I'm not getting an error about bad credentials or failing to connect. This error sounds like the syntax simply isn't accepted, and Docker probably hasn't even come close yet to actually trying to mount the share.

This question is a follow-up to a still unanswered question here: [How would I provide access to my Windows V:\ drive in a docker-compose.yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77384922/how-would-i-provide-access-to-my-windows-v-drive-in-a-docker-compose-yml-file)

Since accessing my network share via an already-mounted Windows drive letter isn't working, I thought I'd try to get to this share over a new SMB connection, but that's getting nowhere either.